Problem with rigid body and animated character
I have a problem to add a bracelets to a animated character, I use MB-LAB ADDON to create the character, and use the default skeleton to animated this one.
I already finish my animation and now I want to add bracelets and jewellery, but I need this react to the animation, I mean I need the bracelets move with the arm in a natural way.
I thought the best way to do this is using physics, but for any reason this didn't work. I tried setting the bracelets as rigid body and the character ass collision, but the bracelets always pass throught the body, tried used parent the bracelets to the low arm bone but didn't work too. So I really don't know how to do this.
I will add differente image of the settings





